# What are the different endings in Dishonored?

Tags: dishonored

In Dishonored the game as I am escaping the prison, I got a prompt that warned me:

> Using stealth and nonlethal approach has benefits. Fewer rats and
>   weepers, some people react favorably, and the final outcome is not as
>   dark.

What are all the different endings? And how much chaos yields them? And what is the optimal ending?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Dishonored has two different endings depending on how you play the game. If you kill everyone you will get the evil ending (high chaos ending). If you don't kill very many people, you will get the good ending (low chaos ending):

- At the good ending you'll save Empress Emily Kaldwin.
- At the evil ending Corvo Attano dies.
- In the high chaos you can still save Emily

You can save Emily at the high chaos ending even if Havelock sees you, by stopping time and using blink to get directly in front of him.

You cannot see an exact value of your current chaos, but here are some tips:

- Weepers count towards your detection value if seen. They also raise the Chaos Rating if killed
- Rewiring traps that result in kills will count towards kill amounts and Chaos level
- Friendly characters do not count towards detection. This includes Rats, Hagfish, River Krust etc. They also do not raise the Chaos Rating when killed. This changes if they see you make a hostile/aggressive action.
- Wolfhounds do not count towards Chaos Rating when killed, however they can discover you and other bodies you leave behind. Best to kill these while hidden
- Killing under 20% of the characters in each mission should ensure the Low Chaos Rating score at the end of each level.
- Chaos Rating can have many effects on each level, such as increased enemy presence or different available items.

Comment: Emily can be saved in one of two ways during the high chaos final mission. You can either remove the whale oil canister and sneak under the bridge, blink up to the left on the small platform, and sneak up to the Admiral and kill him from behind. OR you can approach on the bridge and shoot the Admiral, taking care not to hit Emily. He will lose Emily and she falls, just catching herself on the bridge. Kill the Admiral, then you can save Emily or let her fall. This actually leads to a very different ending from saving her, so there seem to be 2 high chaos endings.

Comment: It is still possible to save Emily without directly killing the Admiral. Use Time Stop (and blink if your Timestop isn't maxed) to reach the pair before they begin to fall. A context option should appear to catch Emily. Corvo will catch Emily as the Admiral attempts to throw both over.

Comment: You can posses the admiral. If you do, Emily will run, and then you can kill the admiral in peace (high chaos). In the end it says you die, though.

Comment: Actually there are 2 types of Chaos, HIGH and LOW, to which both have more than 1 ending. For example in HIGH chaos, saving or not saving emily will throw a different ending. In LOW Chaos, doing it ghost, without harming anyone, without getting caught, without talking to the witch or even doing it very fast will throw different endings/dialogues at the end. I have already seen 4 different endings, so there has to be more because there are several actions that will change the whole game.

Comment: Another way to save Emily on high chaos is just simply shooting the admiral with a crossbow, then go to the ledge and Emily will be hanging there.

Comment: There are three endings. One low chaos, two high chaos.