# Is the "no kills" ending the same as the "low chaos" ending?

Tags: dishonored

I killed five guards in the first chapter (the prison level), but since then (I'm already in Chapter 3) I have had no kills. If I keep going and make sure to maintain low chaos, will I still be able to get the same ending as if I had no kills in the first chapter?

*I realize there is a question that [lists the different endings](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/88864/what-are-the-different-endings) in the game, but I'm trying to get an answer to this question without reading any spoilers.*

Comment: We can't have duplicates just to prevent spoilers.  That said, according to the linked question, there are only two endings.

Comment: This question seems more of a "Does the tutorial count to the chaos rating?" thing than anything else. That said, I'm fairly certain there's no such thing as a "no kills" ending. It's solely based on the overall chaos rating.

Comment: Agreed with @OrigamiRobot.  Having said that, according to the accepted answer to the other question there is only a high and low chaos ending.

Comment: @IQAndreas I realize you realize it.  I am saying that's not how the site works.  If you want a spoiler free version of that answer, you can try asking in [chat].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to go for no kills if you want the low chaos ending. You can still kill people and to have a counterweight to your action, you can do good deeds like saving people from rogue guards and stuff like that.
That will actually lower the chaos done in that mission.

People just tend to stack the low chaos ending with the no kills ending and some others, so that they can get multiple achievements done in one playthrough.